Display User-Specific Data from Looker in a Mobile App Without Granting Looker Access
Hi Stack Overflow community,
I'm currently working on building a mobile application, and I am looking for a way to present user-specific data from Looker to my users, who are my workers. Here is a detailed breakdown of my requirements and constraints:

Multiple Users: The application will have multiple users that will access the data.
Data Presentation: Each user needs to see a specific set of data that is relevant only to them.
No Direct Looker Access: It is crucial that the users do not have direct access to Looker.
User Authentication: I am considering using just my authentication to manage security.
Embedding with SSO: I'm interested in using SSO (Single Sign-On) Embedding with Looker's Embed SDK.

Given these points, I'm looking for guidance on how to achieve this securely and efficiently. Can I even use Looker for this? Is SSO (Single Sign-On) Embedding with Looker's Embed SDK the right way to go?
Thank you in advance for your help!
